# Error C1047: Object file created with an older compiler than other objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a project that I'm building in C++ in Release mode in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on Windows 7 and when I build it I keep getting:

> fatal error C1047: The object or
>   library file '.\Release\foobar.obj'
>   was created with an older compiler
>   than other objects; rebuild old
>   objects and libraries.

The error occurs while linking.

I've tried deleting the specific object file and rebuilding but that doesn't fix it. I've also tried blowing away the whole release build folder and rebuilding but that also didn't fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest reinstalling VS 2008 SP1. Have you installed a different VS (e.g. VS Express) in the meantime? This is known to cause interference with an existing VS installation.

You could try checking the compiler and linker versions by running `cl.exe` and `link.exe` from the Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: I fixed this by reinstalling VS2008 SP1. What happened was I installed VS2008, then SP1, and then the Feature Pack. This created an inconsistency within the compiler, and reinstalling SP1 fixed it.

Comment: Glad you are up and running again!

What seems to have happened is that the tools you used to create your objects were (slightly) older than the compiler provided objects you linked to.

Comment: I've come across the same error, but reinstallation does not solve the problem. I cleaned and rebuilt the project and that error disappeared.

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem but my solution differs:

For me the culprit was that an included external library was compiled with

```
/GL (=Enable link-time code generation under
      C/C++/ Optimization / Whole Program Optimization)
```

using an older visual studio (2005). I rebuild said library in 2005 without /GL and the linker error disappeared in 2008. As MSDN states it has to do with the /LTCG setting, this is set automatically by the /GL flag:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173554%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I ran into this in the build of a third-party library.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find an easy way to disable WholeProgramOptimization from the command line.  After editing the vcproj, setting this option to false everywhere, it worked.

Comment: Yes, this is also clearly documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017), where it states "static libraries or object files compiled using the /GL (Whole program optimization) compiler switch aren't binary-compatible across versions". I recommend you to add this link as well to the answer.

Answer (score 15):

I was able to fix this problem in VS 2015 with the following steps.

[1] (Not sure this was necessary) Turn off /GL in all components

> C/C++ > Optimization > Whole program Optimization > No

In the .VCXPROJ files it's:

```
<WholeProgramOptimization>false</WholeProgramOptimization>
```

Turn off /LTCG

> Librarian > General > Link Time Code Generation

```
<LinkTimeCodeGeneration>false</LinkTimeCodeGeneration>
```

[2] More important step, make sure all components are drawing from the same directories. My main EXE was using:

```
Release Include
$(WindowsSdkDir)include\um;$(WindowsSdkDir)include\shared;$(UniversalCRT_IncludePath);$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include
Release Library
$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSdk_71A_LibraryPath_x86);
```

The .lib was using different directories (wrong):

```
Release Include
$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);
Release Library
$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86);$(NETFXKitsDir)Lib\um\x86
```

I changed the .lib directories to be the same as the .exe, and the compilation error disappeared.

Comment: Turning off LinkTimeCodeGeneration and WholeProgramOptimation did the trick for me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Turning off WholeProgramOptimization worked for me. Thanks:)

Answer (score 8):

Two ways:

1.Update to Sp1 to build the lib

2.Please check your build to make sure that Whole Program Optimization is disabled. For a static lib project, go to the property page and change “Configuration Properties->C/C++->Optimization->Whole Program Optimization” to “No”.

Comment: Also it may help to binary replace `_MSC_VER=XXXX` to the needed version in the old lib files.

Answer (score 5):

Anyone finding this thread looking for answers... I ran into this as well, but it wasn't a SP1 problem or a rebuild problem or a PCH problem... it ended up being a library that was built with a more recent version of VS trying to link into a project on the older VS.  While that sounds obvious, the odd part was VS2008 was reporting that an object that **it compiled** was the cause of the problem which sent me on a wild goose chase...

Comment: This happened to me as well, the culprit was tinyxml2.lib which it turned out I didn't really need so I removed it from the project configuration and the problem disappeared.  Many thanks @mark.

Comment: on vs2022 17.7, find the external link library (.lib) and rebuild it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

It could also be that the offending library was built with a different "Platform Toolset" setting (in Project Properties->General).

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Disagree. Exactly the root cause in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too, and my visual Studio About box reported I had SP1 installed. Apparently that was not entirely true. Investigation on my specific occurance to this problem reveiled the resource compiler seemed to be the culprid. It happened to be an older version, that caused the mentioned error message. My installed hotfixes (Windows update) did not solve that problem. Maybe I missed a crucial one.....

Hopefully we once experience the day developers will actually communicate back the real problem in their generated error messages. :-)
'an older version of a compiler....' come on guys, you can do better than that ;-)

Anyways, here is the downloadlink to the latest SP1 for VS2008 i've used to solve this problem.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I try everything here... and my mistach become of a bad reference and duplicate GUID (between 2010 and 2015 project... the hell of copy/past project)

During project migration from VS2008 to 2010 and 2015. We keep all project version XXX.vxproj (for VS2010) and XXX_2015.vxproj (for VS2015).

And in one of them in 2015 solution we got a reference to 2010 project !

So check REFERENCE... and never duplicate GUID.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but a straight up reinstall did not fix it. I was using the version I found here

https://www.dreamspark.com/Products/Product.aspx?ProductId=9

However, after trawling forums I found that installing VS2008 SP1 Express eliminates this problem. . . .

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=f3fbb04e-92c2-4701-b4ba-92e26e408569

You have to be careful which place you download VS2008 from as different versions of the same Express product are available for download.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173554(v=vs.80).aspx), this error
**The object or library file 'file' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries**
is caused when object files or libraries built with /LTCG are linked together, but where those object files or libraries are built with different versions of the Visual C++ toolset.

This can happen if you begin using a new version of the compiler but do not do a clean rebuild of existing object files or libraries.

**To resolve, rebuild all object files or libraries.**

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have a `.pch` (precompiled header) file somewhere in the project directory and erase it. then rebuild the project.
The best way to get a clean build is using Build->Clean or Build->Rebuild All

**Edit:** Another thing you can try that is pretty much fail safe is to recreate the project file in a new directory from only the source files.
If that works then you can incrementally compare the old project with the new one to see what does wrong.