# VC 2008 fatal error C1047 cplus fix?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Hello everyone i am using VC 2008 c++ and i got some project that isn't mine. 
The project rebuilds successfully, but the problem is the project doesn't create all the `.lib` files that are needed for another project and so i got:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: application_manager, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Linking...
1>LINK : warning LNK4224: /OPT:NOWIN98 is no longer supported;  ignored
1>fatal error C1047: The object or library file 'C:\Users\modestas\Desktop\代码\server\../contrib/lib/tinyxml/\tinyxml_stl.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
1>Build log was saved at "file://C:\Users\modestas\Desktop\代码\server\temp\application_manager\Release\BuildLog.htm"
1>application_manager - 1 error(s), 1 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

this project already has `tinyxml_stl.lib`, but the tinyxml project doesn't build a new one so i got this error how to fix this error?

Comment: Get a newer version of the library?

Comment: In a solution there is 16 projects two of them don't build succesfully. One that dosn't build succesfully gives me this error, the project who is responsible to build these libs builds only 4-5 of 6-7, on of those ~2 is 'tinyxml_stl.lib' i want a solution to include the old one lib to project and fix this error(the old one is builded it was already in folder).

Comment: i am thinking about /LTCG but i don't know how to disable it and if i disable it will it harm project?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the tinyxml_stl project (or getting a binary for it that was built with VS 2008?)

Comment: cleaning yes, the lib is included to project in another words it's hand made 'lib'. You can't find it in internet. :)

Comment: I would make sure your application_manager project is using the correct lib (built with VS 2008). Maybe delete all tinyxml_stl.lib files before building? If all else fails [reinstall VS2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837073/error-c1047-object-file-created-with-an-older-compiler-than-other-objects)

Comment: Nope MarkB42, you didin't understand. All project build succesfully all 14 from 16 projects. Problem is for two projects that don't build is application_manager, it gives 'was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries'. This means 'fatal error C1047', how can i fix this error and it would use the old one 'lib' file is it possible? if no then how to ignore this error or disable this function for checking if lib is builded with this compiler or no?

Comment: I understand. I am trying to offer suggestions on fixing it. For some reason VS thinks your tinyxml was built with an older compiler version. So either the tinyxml that you are linking to was created with an older version, or VS is in error (which is why I provided the link). Is application_manager linking to the same .lib file that is created by the tinyxml_stl project?

Comment: the project which (i think - becouse this project isn't mine) create this lib file dosn't create it. It creates tinyxml.lib and some others(those lib files are used by another projects so they all are builded fine), so yes the 'lib' file is in older version than my compiler i am asking how to make vc 2008 to ignore this fact and use old one(i want a solution which won't affect the project). MarkB42, thanks for help. :)

Comment: As far as I know you can't use the .lib created from an older version of the compiler. So you might need to copy the tinyxml project into a second location and compile it with VS2008. Then you would have two versions of your tinyxml_stl.lib; One for VS2008 and one for the older compiler version. Any project built in VS2008 that links tinyxml_stl can then use the one for VS2008. Then you would avoid mixing binaries created from different compiler versions.

Comment: I want to say that project which is responsible for creating all tinyxml libs creates only 4-5 lib from 6-7. So it dosn't create 'tinyxml_stl.lib' only the old one which was included in project folder is usable in this situation, how to bypass this error without deleting lib include part or harming project?

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying. The error message, as you posted it, says that VS2008 can't finish the linking step of compiling the application_manager project because the file "C:\Users\modestas\Desktop\代码\server\../contrib/lib/tinyxml/\tinyxml_stl.lib" was built with an older version of the compiler. You need to link to a version of tinyxml_stl.lib that was built with the same compiler version that you are using to build application_manager. There is no way around that. So whatever project creates tinyxml_stl.lib must be built with the same compiler version.

Comment: "I have no idea what you are saying. The error message, as you posted it, says that VS2008 can't finish the linking step of compiling the application_manager project because the file "C:\Users\modestas\Desktop\代码\server\../contrib/lib/tinyxml/\tinyxml_stl.lib" was built with an older version of the compiler." Yes i know that. i only have already build 'lib' i don't have new one and project which(I guess should create but dosn't create needed 'lib' in my case) so how to fix this error without building this 'lib' and using old one, i was thinking about ('/LTCG') - disables identifier of 'lib'...

Comment: You can try disabling `/LTCG` but really I would modify the lib you link to in application_manager so that it links to the correct binary created by your tinyxml project. Using the correct binaries is the correct fix.

Comment: If you found a solution you should add it as an answer and mark it as the correct answer to help anyone int he future who might have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by `tinyxml_stl.lib` being compiled using an older version of the compiler than you are using to compile `application_manager`

Since your tinylib project no longer creates this file as output I assume that this is simply the result of the previous developer leaving you with a mess of files. If you change your `application_manager` to link to the correct binaries created by tinyxml and remove the link to `tinyxml_stl.lib` you should be able to compile.

Comment: Yes, but if i remove the link to tinyxml_stl.lib i really doubt that i won't get any errors from code, becouse lib file is used for script? So what do you suggest? will come back for answer tomorrow.

Comment: Your `tinyxml_stl.lib` is most likely an old binary of the tinyxml project. It is best to remove that link and link to the current binaries. You might get errors in your code, but you should be able to fix them. Trying to hack around it using an old lib file will probably just cause problems later.

Comment: delete the link out it's crazy, becouse i got ~30 errors, sp hwat you suggest to delete about ~14 functions and about ~20 lines of code so that it would work i think it's crazy i will think about this and will try my luck to fix but i really doubt it's the best way. Will write my news.

Comment: Did you also add the link to the binaries from the tinyxml project? You will get an error for everything from tinyxml_stl.lib that is deprecated in the updated tinyxml. Understanding your code and what it does is **not** crazy.

Comment: I am also not suggesting that you just delete all of the lines of code that cause errors. I am suggesting that you fix them so that they work correctly with the tinyxml library.