# VS2008-2013, error C1047: Object file created with an older compiler than other objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a project that I'm building in C++ in Release mode in Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7 that worked fine a month ago. Since then I installed Visual Studio 2013 Express and worked on a new project. Now I'm trying to get back on VS2008 (on my old project) and when I build I keep getting:

```
fatal error C1047: The object or library file '...\lib\Lua.lib' was created with 
an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
```

The error occurs while linking.

I reinstalled VS 2008 SP1 and still get the error. If I rebuild Lua.lib, the error is solved but then it I get :

```
fatal error C1047: The object or library file '...\lib\LuaBind.lib' was created with 
an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
```

Do I have to rebuild all my dependancies?

Comment: Yes, you have to. Every imported library _should_ be built with same compiler version.

Comment: Yes it was compiled with VS2008. My new VS2013 project do not use the same dependancies. I didn't change anything and a month later it does not build anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error C1047: Object file created with an older compiler than other objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837073/error-c1047-object-file-created-with-an-older-compiler-than-other-objects)