# Upgrading VS2017 15.2 to 15.3 broke third party libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I recently updated my Visual Studio version to the latest (mostly because of an automatic update rather than me willingly doing so). This proceeded to break my compiler when linking in third party libraries that were built using 15.2 instead of the current version of 15.3. The error I'm seeing is:

"Library_Name_here.lib" was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries

I am looking for either ideas for solutions to avoid a re-compile of these libraries, but if one does not exist, I am looking for a way to compile the libraries to be version agnostic to not have to keep recompiling every time that vs updates.

Comment: This will depend on what that library does and how you use it and what its interface is.  The most version independent way to handle it is to wrap the library in COM, but that is not what you call easy if the interface is rich.  A full answer requires concrete specific details about the library.

Comment: @Yakk I am quite surprised that VS has a breaking ABI change (the only reason which should prevent interlinking) in a minor upgrade.

Comment: @sergeyA Surrprising to me as well, but that isn't what the OP asked about?  I kniw they updated the compiler in 15.3, but am surprised by that generating an error, as it should be a minor version update not a major one.  Maybe the OP beeds to quote the error entirely verbatim instead of copy pasting one part...

Comment: Aha: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837073/error-c1047-object-file-created-with-an-older-compiler-than-other-objects -- library maybe compiled with LTCG enabled, and project compiled with it as well, newer compiler cannot be expected to LTCG code from an earlier (even minor difference) version.  Fix: recompile old library without link time code generation, and minor version changes stop bothering you?  Maybe that is; need more info from OP.

Comment: @Yakk I think you might be on to something. I think this is actually exactly what I was looking for and probably would have fond with another week of searching. I had basically googled everything related except for the issue number itself

Comment: Not really surprising. You should *always* build *all* parts of your program (including libraries) with the *exact same* compiler. There is usually *no guarantee* of compatibility between different compiler versions (even minor versions) - don't depend on such compatibility even if it sometimes *seems* to exist.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to mix and match code (object files or static libraries) compiled by different versions of the compiler in the same binary.

To quote [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx) on that:

> To avoid run-time errors that are difficult to detect and diagnose, we
>   recommend that you never statically link to binaries that were
>   compiled by using different versions of the compiler. Also, when you
>   upgrade an EXE or DLL project, make sure to upgrade the libraries that
>   it links to. If you're using CRT (C Runtime) or STL (Standard Template
>   Library) types, don't pass them between binaries (including DLLs) that
>   were compiled by using different versions of the compiler. For more
>   information, see [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL
>   Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx).

The solution is therefore to recompile all third-party static libraries with the new compiler.

Comment: I understand that it isn't a great idea, but I am still looking for a work around

Comment: @Rich *but I am still looking for a work around * -- A static library is nothing more than object files packaged in a larger file.  Those object files were generated by another compiler version.   Imagine, would you risk compiling half of your project with an older compiler, half of your project with a newer compiler and then link that together, hoping all works?

Comment: In most cases you would be correct. However, since I'm the one updating all of the third party libraries (for the entire project) in one go, I can deal with the consequences. Especially since I'm trying to freeze the visual studio version after to hopefully never see this kind of error again in the future

Comment: @Rich there is no workaround. Just always build *everything* with the same compiler.

Comment: @Rich If Microsoft recommand it and you have a provlem, you already know what you have to do. Recompile the libraries or ask third party to do so...

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues few months ago when i upgraded VS2015 to VS2017 and one of my big project that i was running on visual studio 2015 stopped working. That project had several class libraries and external DLLs added.

So what I did was, Uninstalled the upgraded version of visual studio 2017 and re-installed the complete visual studio 2017 from MSDN website (selecting the default selection of features). And then i loaded my Project in VS2017 fresh copy and added the reference of all external libraries and it worked.

I suggest you to try the same

Comment: It isn't my project that isn't compiling, its the third party libraries within the project that were technically compiled in an older version that the compiler is rejecting.

Comment: @Rick why don't you just re-compile those third party libraries (with rhe new compiler) and be on your merry way? Shouldn't take long..

Comment: As I already explained, I don't want to have to do this process every time visual studio releases an update

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, based on this other SO answer: [Error C1047: Object file created with an older compiler than other objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837073/error-c1047-object-file-created-with-an-older-compiler-than-other-objects)

Recompile the other library without link time code generation enabled (`/GL` and `/LTCG`).  With it enabled the library expects the linker to do most of the compiling, and you cannot expect one version of the compiler to finish the compiling another version started.

Do not disable it in your active project, as it improves performance significantly.  Just in the library.

Major compiler versions may still require rebuilding the 3rd party library, but not minor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from within VS2017. It allows you to use tool sets going all the way back to VS2008

See this for details!

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/24/stuck-on-an-older-toolset-version-move-to-visual-studio-2015-without-upgrading-your-toolset/

Hope that helps!